# Getting an "undeclared type 'MKMapView'" error

Tags: ios

Added a map to the storyboard, added Mapping capabilities to project and getting this error

Nothing in Google or StackOverflow

Comment: I imported MapKit framework but I have experienced in same case.
And so I have written following sentence. import MapKit My error is fixed.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Pathetically silly: forgot to import MapKit

```
import MapKit
```

Adding the answer so it's available in Google

Comment: That's so silly of me! Thanks for posting this answer.

Comment: Not really pathetic. With all the drag and dropping you do and things that happen behind the scenes in Xcode, you'd think if you drag a mapview onto the controller and it's added, it would import the MapKit. I am glad I found your answer.

Comment: I use Mapbox, so `import Mapbox`